# Cannot connect to Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, public-key

I have been added to a google cloud project with the owner role (as well as the Compute OS Admin Login in case that makes any difference), but for some reason, I cannot connect via the SSH button (that keeps retrying) or via the terminal after adding a public key on the METADATA section (Permission denied).

- The disk has space
- The "Block project-wide SSH keys" is disabled

Any help is much appreciated.

Update! Only now figured out that even after erasing all the keys on the project and instance, my colleague is still able to connect even though we are almost sure that the OS Login is not activated. I'm new to this so I have no idea why that is.

Comment: And the firewall accepts connections on port 22?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Comment: @FerreginaPelona checked and yes it is set to "Apply to all"

Comment: If your colleague is using the Google Cloud Console GUI to connect, the connection is being made via IAP (Identity Aware Proxy). That method uses IAM permissions to manage connections. Google has good documentation on Compute Engine that covers these items.

Comment: It says that "Identity-Aware Proxy API is not enabled".

Comment: You cannot manage the SSH keys that are used to connect from the browser. Those SSH keys are managed by Google and are controlled by IAM roles. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser